# Webform - Show/Hide fields based on day of the week selected from Datepicker

Tags: webforms

I have a little issue with a webform. 
I am setting a booking system and some items are only available on some days of the week. 
I have modified the date field to be a textbox with popup calendar 
I need to show/ hide some field based on the Day of The Week selected ( if Day is Tuesday or Day is Friday then Show the fields, otherwise, hid them) 
Any help is welcome, because with the conditionals, i can only do it based on date not on the day itself.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably with jQuery. To get the datepicker field value, and convert it to a weekday, you can follow these steps.

- Add this function to the JavaScript file

  ```js
  // Accepts a Date object or date string that is recognized by Date.parse()
  function getDayOfWeek(date) {
    var dayOfWeek = new Date(date).getDay();    
    return isNaN(dayOfWeek) ? null : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6][dayOfWeek];
  }
  ```
- Use this code to get the value from the datepicker field

  ```js
  var datepicker = $('#your_datepicker_id').datepicker("getDate");
  var today = new Date();
  if (!today.getDay() == getDayOfWeek(datepicker)) {
    $('.field-names-to-hide').hide();
  }
  ```